# The term 'Connect-PartnerCenter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I want to login to Microsoft Partner center using power shell.. so i install the related module:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Install-Module -Name PartnerCenter -AllowClobber -Scope AllUsers
```

But when i try to connect to the partner center i got this error:-

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-PartnerCenter
Connect-PartnerCenter : The term 'Connect-PartnerCenter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-PartnerCenter
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-PartnerCenter:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: After installing the module, did you `Import-Module PartnerCenter` in your code?

Comment: @Theo will get this error `Import-Module : The specified module 'PartnerCenter' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any
module directory.`

Comment: Did you run the `Install-Module` for all users running as Administrator?

Comment: @Theo yes already did that

Comment: Close all the powershell sessions and try `Connect-PartnerCenter` again, does it work?

Comment: @JoyWang already did that ... did not work either

Comment: Could you check if the module was installed successfully via `Get-InstalledModule -Name PartnerCenter`?

Comment: @JoyWang yes it is there `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-InstalledModule -Name PartnerCenter

Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
3.0.10     PartnerCenter                       PSGallery            Microsoft Partner Center - cmdlets for managing ...`

Comment: @JohnJohn Make sure your environment var is correct, follow https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/01/import-module-specified-module-not-loaded-because-no-valid-module-file-found-in-any-module-directory.html

Comment: @JohnJohn Just to let you know: your problem is not reproducible. If I install this module - like you did - on a fresh Windows 10, I can call this cmdlet successfully. May be that helps for your TSHOOT. It might be related to a special configuration on your particular system.

Comment: @JohnJohn As Joy Wang already suggested, you might have a broken PSModulePath. For further debugging, can you please share the content of `$env:PSModulePath`? And what is the output of `(Get-InstalledModule -Name PartnerCenter).InstalledLocation`?

Comment: Modules are read in the order of `$env:PSModulePath` (where the shared "system" modules are usually last). Check each path for leftovers of earlier user-based installations and remove the `PartnerCenter` subfolders (except for the one in the last modulepath, or simply just reinstall after).

Comment: @JohnJohn Do you use different versions of PowerShell? I have the same issue if I install the module on PS 7 and try to connect by PS5. If is your case, try use the same PS version for installation and connection.

Comment: What is the version of Powershell are you using ? is it greater that 5.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the pure requirement is only these 2:

To run Partner Center PowerShell in PowerShell 5.1 on Windows:

Update to Windows PowerShell 5.1 if needed. If you're on Windows 10, you already have PowerShell 5.1 installed.
Install .NET Framework 4.7.2 or later.

I did it on new win10 machine (azure vm), worked fine.